# Unable to link static library to main program

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to link [this](https://github.com/bytemaster/fc) external library which i have compiled using cmake which give me `libfc.a` file. I tried to link this static library to my `main.cpp` file but unable to access static library.

```
//main.cpp
int main()
{
    fc::unsigned_int  abi_sequence  = 0;
}
```

I've tried:

```
g++ main.cpp libfc.a -o main.out
g++ main.cpp -L. -lfc -o main.out
```

I've tried other examples from other stackoverflow posts but i didn't help me at all.

Comment: What are the errors you get when you build? And do you include the ***header file*** which defines the `fc` namespace (or class) and the `fc::unsigned_int` type?

Comment: Your issue is about order. The libraries to link with must be specified right after the module that depends on them.

Comment: @Fareanor Libraries should be after the modules (object or source file) that depends on them, they don't have to be absolute last.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're right, my bad (corrected).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, i'm receiving `main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:3:5: error: ‘fc’ has not been declared
     fc::unsigned_int  abi_sequence  = 0;`.

Do i have to also include header which define this type?

Comment: @Fareanor, I've also tried that example but answer didn't work for me.

Comment: @Farhan-TroonTechnologies Yes you need to include the header files as well. The header files defines things like classes, namespaces, types, etc. The library file itself contains the *code*, the implementations of the functions themselves.

Comment: @Farhan-TroonTechnologies Of course you have to include the header.

Comment: @Fareanor, library headers are in include folder and main files are in src folder. When i include a header then it unable to find other header file. Can you send me link or any example that could help me?

Comment: @Farhan-TroonTechnologies if you don't use a buildsystem such as cmake, that has to be done manually with `-I./my_include_dir`

Comment: You have to write the path if the header is not in the same directory. For example, if the current source file is in _cpp_ folder, you can write `#include "../include/my_header.h"`. Or better, specify the include directory in the compilation command as @GuillaumeRacicot did suggest.

Comment: @Fareanor, yeah header are not in same directory. I have tried it but it contain a lot of header and i need to change on all of them. Is there any other solution where i don't have to change the library code?

Comment: @Farhan-TroonTechnologies Yes, read the comment of Guillaume Racicot. This is way better and what you need.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, I just checked it. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Farhan-TroonTechnologies I'd suggest you to checkout a build system such as CMake (modern cmake) that will automate the configuration of the whole project.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, I will check that. Thanks to you, i'm able to specify the header path but it's couldn't find src path or definition which give me error.
`undefined reference to fc::sha256::sha256()`